# Random edge addition in a networkx Garph

Tags: python, networkx

I have generated a graph using `networkx` which randomly adds any two nodes of the network:

```
G=nx.Graph()
node_list=list(range(30))
G.add_nodes_from(node_list)
edges=104
while edges>0:
    i=random.choice(node_list)
    j=choice([a for a in node_list if not a in [i]])
    G.add_edge(i,j)
    edges-=1
nx.draw(G)
```

Now what if I run a loop as:

```
for e in G.edges():
 ...
```

Will my edges be accessed in a sequential manner(maybe first created to last created) or randomly from the list of edges? I need this because I have to access each edge's betweenness centrality ,and if the centralities are not defined sequentially in the `edge_betweenness_centrality()` dictionary, some other approach needs to be tried.

Comment: Several comments: `j=choice([a for a in node_list if not a in [i]])` is inefficient.  It takes a list, then rebuilds the list all except 1 entry and chooses an element from that list.  Instead try  `j=i  ;    while j == i:   j = random.choice(node_list)`

Comment: Also, instead of counting down,  replace `while edges>0` with `for counter in range(104):`  This will make it much clearer that you're running through the process 104 times.

Comment: And an even better way to choose a random pair is to use the `choices` option in `random`.   `i=j=1;     while i==j:   i,j = random.choices(nodelist, k=2)`    (the test for i==j is because the choice is done with replacement).

Comment: Can you explain why you need the edges sequentially a bit better?  `edge_betweenness_centrality` returns a dictionary.

Comment: I need to plot a correlation between the edge centrality and a 'capacity' assigned to the edge. I will read out each of the centralities from the `nx.edge_betweenness_centrality` dictionary and correlate it with the edge capacity.Now, if the edges are not accesssed in the same manner as the centralities are,they will be messed up.

Comment: I've had a simular issue once and, to avoid it, I did save the order at which they were accessed. The extra computational efforts were worth it for me, since I only had to run that script once for a huge graph.

Comment: The concerns you have about order are irrelevant for a dictionary.  You can control the order that it produces the values.  I recommend reading a bit more about how they work.